# Что происходит при создании замыкания?

Tags: knockoutjs, javascript

Собственно имеет такой код (arr - массив свойств) (KnockoutJS):

```
for (var prop in arr) {
        var val = this[arr[prop]];
        if (val && ko.isSubscribable(val)) {
            (function (e, p) {
                e[p].subscribe(function (value) {
                    e.processChange(p, value);
                });
            })(this, arr[prop]);
        }
    }
```

Вопрос в следующем: что происходит с this при передаче его во внутрь замыкания?
Копируется только ссылка? если так, то метод subscribe и processChange вызовутся у объекта this этого кода?

Причины сомнений:

В далеком от этого куске кода у объекта, который тут был this, у одного из его свойств вызывается кнокаутовский сеттер, который дергает эту подписку.

НО! объект, у которого вызывается сеттер не равен объекту `e`, когда я останавливаюсь в коде подписки по брейкпоинту. А код подписки вызывается как раз на реакцию сеттера.

В общем, ЧЗХ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объекты и массивы передаются по ссылке **в любом случае** (и как аргументы и как замыкаемые переменные)

```
var obj1 = {}, obj2 = {};
var func = (function(obj ,prop, value){
    return function(){
        obj1[prop] = value; // как замыкаемая переманная
        obj[prop] = value;  // как аргумент
    }    
})(obj2, 'prop', 'xxx');
obj1['prop'] = 'value';
obj2['prop'] = 'value';
func(); 
console.log(obj1); // {prop:'xxx'}
console.log(obj2); // {prop:'xxx'}
```

следовательно, в `e` будет(должна быть) ссылка на объект `this`, т.о. метод `subscribe` и `processChange` вызовутся у объекта `this` **этого** кода. Возможно, это нюансы `knockout`, или вы потеряли контекст где-то=)